# Where can I find a profile name in AWS for credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to have a credentials file. It looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY
aws_session_token = TOKEN

[Alice]
aws_access_key_id = Alice_access_key_ID
aws_secret_access_key = Alice_secret_access_key

[Bob]
aws_access_key_id = Bob_access_key_ID
aws_secret_access_key = Bob_secret_access_key
```

I read [this article](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs), the guy refers all these `[Alice]`, `[Bob]` as `profile name`s but doesn't say a word where to get them in AWS. In my newly created AWS account I have only this. No any `profile name`:

[image]

Where can I find those profile names? May that `Account Name` or `Account Id` on the screenshot be a `profile name`? or is `profile name` an email I stated on registration?

Comment: They're just arbitrary labels

Answer (score 4):

You just make up whatever labels you want. They are only used locally by the SDK to figure out which set of credentials to read from the local credential store. AWS doesn't know anything about them.

Answer (score 0):

They are arbitrary labels and I use them [IAM username] for ease of use.